# How many comic book continuities are there in the Power Rangers universe, or is it one "Shared" continuity for all?

Tags: comics, parallel-universe, continuity, alternate-history, power-rangers

The *Mighty Morphin Power Rangers* have had a few comic adaptations, those most notably from Boom Studios.

The story essentially takes the original premise nd even characters from the 1993 show, and pits them in current times (2010s-2020), following most of the story beats and details.

[image]

However, there is some confusion in terms of timelines/continuity, mostly from one of its most popular stories, *The Shattered Grid.*

[image]

Some stories follow the original 6 ranger team even as they become adults and have kids of their own, or as they have moved on to later Ranger adventures. This gets even *more* confusing when future "canon" versions of new Ranger teams from the nearly 30 years of the show *also* get individual comics, or feature in stories:

[image]

Power Rangers from *Power Rangers Samurai*

[image]

Ranger Team from *Power Rangers Time Force*

[image]

Power Ranger Mega Force team. This last team is *especially* notable because they, as a "descendent" team, actually draw abilities from all the *previous* Ranger teams that came before, indicating a 10 year or more history.

Adding to this is the _alternate reality" Power Rangers from the 2017 "reboot" film which features essentially the same "characters" from the 1993 series, but they are different individuals, both physically and emotionally, with different backstories.

[image]

This isn't even taking into account the various Marvel and other comic adaptations that were made in the 90s; I'm referencing them here for clarity, but don't believe they impact current continuity. What *does* need to be taken into account, however, is that these stories *do* cross over with other comic book "realities, such a that of the *justice League* and the *teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles*

[image]

[image]

There's also an alternate story/version called "Go Go Power Rangers"; I'm uncertain exactly how  this story fits into the main continuity, along with *Shattered Grid* and the others.

[image]

Is there any clear "Timeline" or continuity for these comics?

Are they multiple universes, or all share the same universe?

Can someone suggest a reading order?

As such